# User keeps getting banned, yet keeps making new accounts to ask questions

Tags: support, multiple-accounts, ban

This user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/761669/errorerrorerror

Keeps making new accounts.

He/She just asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683575/change-source-of-calendar-how-to-do-it-with-a-button
Using a new username.

I know it is the same user because they admitted on chat to making more than one account because they kept getting BANNED on Stack Overflow, also because the same @ErrorErrorError user has been on chat for a while asking about the building of his/her site.

Can this please be remedied?

---

This is the search on SO for the user's website and the number of questions with different users **all** using the same site: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com

---

List of known usernames:

- [user807295](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807295/user807295)
- [LiquidNitrogen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800184/liquidnitrogen)
- [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839048/james)
- [Sdfsd Sdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828582/sdfsd-sdf)
- [Rock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841015/rock)
- [ErrorErrorError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761669/errorerrorerror) <-- I believe this one was the 1st main account

Comment: Just curious - did the merge result in the user getting enough rep to downvote (125), subsequently causing the [revenge downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98500/user-revenge-all-my-questions-were-downvoted-in-the-past-hour)?

Comment: @RobHruska: Talk about your unintended consequences...

Comment: @RobHruska -- i did not think of that...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can't confirm LiquidNitrogen yet, but the other five are definitely the same person. Merging now. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: the user admited to being LiquidNitrogen on chat

Comment: @Neal: Can you link please?

Comment: see the response here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=921814#921814

Comment: i see all was merged but `user80795`, is there a reason for that?

Comment: I don't like to merge without ironclad proof of identity. Was trying to decide whether the circumstantial evidence was strong enough. By the way, there was another which you hadn't found; I thought you were looking at the same five socks I was elsewhere.

Comment: ahh ok. is there any way of reducing this user down to 1? he/she just said that they will still create more accounts now....http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1008002#1008002

Comment: i like helping this user, i just dont like SO being abused as it is now.

Comment: what was the sixth one? (im sure there are even more than that.... they are hard to find and i dont have access to IP address data)

Comment: I don't remember. I got it from the email address. The IP is shared among quite a lot of people, so I can't just go by that.

Comment: mmyers -- ha, the user used the same email address throughout? wow. he wanted to get caught....

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1008068#1008068 @mmyers ...