# User revenge? All my questions were downvoted in the past hour

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

I asked this question on meta about 2 hours ago: [User keeps getting banned, yet keeps making new accounts to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98484/user-keeps-getting-banned-yet-keeps-making-new-accounts-to-ask-questions)

Since then it seems almost every one of my questions was downvoted once after the @ErrorErrorError user complained about it on chat.

Here is a link to my rep: https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal?tab=reputation

Can these votes please be reversed because downvotes on questions dont cost anything to downvoter....

---

chat links:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1008632#1008632
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1008733#1008733

-- also according to that user he ignores me on chat now, so he will not respond.

---

Please see here for a summary of who and why someone multi-upvoted me accidentally: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1008791#1008791

---

**ALSO** This user in question just got 2, count 'em 2, badges for all the downvoting he did. Can those be rescinded?

Comment: Said user has been nothing but trouble for the JavaScript chat room as well.

Comment: User in question baits chatroom into off topic rage-fests.

Comment: There's an automatic fraud-detection system that should take care of these downvotes.

Comment: @Anna how often does that run?

Comment: @AnnaLear -- also how do i report that user, he has stated multiple times on chat that he will create more accounts (again) and the like

Comment: @Neal It runs every 24 hours, likely sometime around midnight UTC.

Comment: @Neal You can flag any of the user's posts and provide relevant information and links there.

Comment: @Anna they were flagged. all that seems to do is remove them though

Comment: @Neal I can't speak for SO moderators, but I'm sure they're exploring options. There's only so much that can be done to deter a user from coming back when they're an open proxy away from creating more accounts.

Comment: @Anna thats why im sure my original question will need to be expanded soon due to that user creating more and more accounts

Comment: Although it does seem that he may be the one responsible for downvoting all your posts, it doesn't make retaliatory downvoting on his posts right either.  This isn't necessarily directed at you Neal, but for whomever is doing the downvoting.

Comment: @JeffMercado -- it was **not** me. it might be some people on the javascript chat room. It was definitely **not** me. that is just childish

Comment: @Neal: Ok good to know, it just had to be said.  ;)

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: (un)fortunately, rather a lot of this user's posts are of poor quality, so they could just be legitimate votes due to the increased attention...

Comment: @cam: But usually those votes would accumulate over time or be received when it was initially asked.  I'm not defending the quality of the posts (I haven't actually looked at enough of them) but looking at his rep history (when I looked at it earlier), he had received a good deal of downvotes on different posts for the day.  So legitimate, unlikely.  I will probably all disappear by the end of the day though.

Comment: @AdamLear The auto-fraud detection system never seemed to work where I've had questions downvoted serially. By that I mean, I will have a S.O. question up for months, maybe even a year, and then I'll get two or 3 downvotes in the space of a few hours. This happened to me yesterday, after I made a comment on another Stack forum. In fact, that's how it usually happens with me. I make  comment that doesn't agree with a high ranking Stack member, and almost like clockwork I can expect multiple downvotes within the next 24 hours. They stay.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The system will pick it up.

I had someone blow their daily 30 votes on downvoting every one of my last 30 answers. A day later, I had my 60 rep back and account was suspended.

And my stalker got badges too...

Comment: Funny that my proposal to punish serial downvoters was downvoted into the sink. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98055/punish-serial-downvoting

Comment: @gbn -- yes it was resolved all erroneous voting has been removed.