# "This answer has been awarded bounty worth 50 reputation by " - bounty received from nobody?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I've just found one post which has awarded bounty from nobody on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044359/twilio-rest-api-call-making-not-working-s/7110690#7110690) answer. HTML code looks like

```
<span class="bounty-award" title="This answer has been awarded bounty worth 50 reputation by ">+50</span>
```

I have found nothing about bounty in history, even [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7044359/timeline) has no evidence about bounty.

Is it bug?

Also, if it's merged account, it should be rollbacked. It's the same problematic [guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98484/164007)

Comment: Probably a deleted user. Given that it's a self answer I suspect sock puppetry.

Comment: @ChrisF: And given that he's responding to himself in the comments, I'd say that's very likely indeed.

Comment: This guy is like fungus that won't go away. I have to say that cases like this, where the user keeps using proxies to churn out sockpuppets, are the only time I would support hellbanning.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the wording in the answer ("you," "your"), I'm guessing that user had a sock that awarded it a bounty, which later got merged.

Wilder speculation:
Since both the answer and the question currently appear to have the same OP, we know a merge was performed. Since the only bounty info remaining is about the winner and not the offerer, I'm thinking the sock account was probably deleted or even destroyed after the merge was performed. I suspect that this combination of actions is what's leading to the weird behavior. Again: I do **not** have enough firsthand experience with how account moderation tools work to be sure about this. I'm just going off of past Meta posts/discussions.

Comment: Maybe one of merged accounts ? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98484/164007

Comment: Shouldn't that show his merged name then? Why would it show nothing?

Comment: Aha! I don't usually post answers with guesses, especially accusing ones, but I was sure I'd seen this account name before. Good job beating me to finding the reference.

Comment: @PopularDemand this user is famous for sock puppets -- the links in my answer are just a few of the offences

Comment: This is what I had thought too, so I'm relabeling your speculation as "reasonable".

Answer (score 2):

This user is the same user as a few of my meta questions including:
[User keeps getting banned, yet keeps making new accounts to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98484/user-keeps-getting-banned-yet-keeps-making-new-accounts-to-ask-questions)
[User revenge? All my questions were downvoted in the past hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98500/user-revenge-all-my-questions-were-downvoted-in-the-past-hour)

This user has (and had) many many sock puppet account which they used to downvote as they deemed necessary and add rep point to themselves via bounties and other hacks.

Comment: I have posted link in question about this already and I know about sockpupetting. This is bug report, though, not a request to tell me why and what does it happen. Thanks though

Comment: @genesis -- he got alot of badges off this and i am sure the bounty rep was removed. (although i could be mistaken)