# Bounty notice for bounty offered by deleted/banned user has blank username

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, deleted-accounts

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11694546/698590), a bounty was offered by a user apparently no longer active on the site. The bounty notification is now displaying incorrectly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEvwu.png]

This should be changed to have *something* in place of the blank. i.e.

> "This question has an open bounty worth +x reputation from an inactive user ending in y days"

Comment: Same issue in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11694546/revisions)

Comment: As a bit more background. Yesterday a ragequitting user drained away all his rep on all his accounts in the entire network with bounties. On SO he left [3 massive bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month). I flagged this yesterday and the user was deleted. But the bounties stayed. Before the user was removed, only 2 of the 3 bounties showed up in the user's profile. But all 3 showed up in the user's reputation history.

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense for the bounties to disappear when the user's account is deleted.

Comment: What's all that junk you have under the title?

Comment: @casperOne [Question Dashboard](http://stackapps.com/questions/2054/question-dashboard-greasemonkey-script)

Comment: `This question has an open bounty worth +x reputation from someone who couldn't take it any more ending in y days`

Comment: @YannisRizos Sounds reasonable although that could also somewhat backfire in a situation where the OP decides to ragequit afer having offered a bounty. (i.e. the bounty is not part of the whole ragequit process)

Comment: I feel like there was a similar issue a long time ago involving Pollyanna, a deletion and a bounty that had no expiration date, but I can't find it.

Comment: Ditto, @Bart. If someone reasonably intended to pay out a bounty, and someone else put forth the effort to earn it, they should not lose it.

Comment: Ah, I guess this is an extension of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123504/bounty-notices-are-attributed-to-no-one-when-the-owner-is-deleted), which makes (some) sense.

Comment: The bounty notice actually does (still) attribute ownerless bounties to Community in the normal case, but I imagine it's getting tripped up here because the bounty itself doesn't appear in the question's revision history. My speculative explanation for that would be that maybe a moderator attempted to refund the bounty after the user had been deleted and the system wasn't prepared for that, but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We just fixed a recently introduced bug in our close-vote-aging code, which caused it to be a bit ...overzealous: it aged away some non-close votes as well, such the bounty "vote" in this case. As such, mods encountered an error when trying to remove the open bounty on the post in question. The bug and the bad data have been fixed up. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 18):

This is a bit more involved than just someone offering a bounty and then requesting deletion. Prior to the user's deletion, a moderator attempted to refund this bounty - it failed, sorta.

I originally thought it failed after deleting the history but before actually removing the bounty. BUT THE RABBIT HOLE GOES DEEPER THAN THAT, MY FRIENDS...

Turns out, it's not a rogue *moderator* at all... It seems our friendly vote-fraud script has a dark side. He's been sneaking around, late at night, deleting bounty records. Check out the damage this rogue robot has wrought:

- [Cannot figure out why WebGL will not draw a triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507703/cannot-figure-out-why-webgl-will-not-draw-a-triangle)
- [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/javascript-change-img-src)
- [Migration of existing folder/file structure to Plone using funnelweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949620/migration-of-existing-folder-file-structure-to-plone-using-funnelweb)
- [Sphinx vs. MySql - Search through list of friends (efficiency/speed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762147/sphinx-vs-mysql-search-through-list-of-friends-efficiency-speed)
- [What's the "gadget vulnerability"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490844/whats-the-gadget-vulnerability)
- [Layout algorithm that understands compass rose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924150/layout-algorithm-that-understands-compass-rose)
- [How to debug an application without using an IDE and without understanding of the program flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919018/how-to-debug-an-application-without-using-an-ide-and-without-understanding-of-th)
- [all in one social oauth/login button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812656/all-in-one-social-oauth-login-button)

...UNATTRIBUTED BOUNTIES, ALL OF THEM.

[image: Enforcement Droids are SOOO unreliable]

Can this inhuman death merchant be stopped, BEFORE IT DESTROYS US ALL?

Comment: I did in fact notice that the user initially had all 3 bounties associated. Then it went down to 2. I don't remember whether I flagged it before or after it went down to 2.