# Bounty by deleted account is not showing correctly

Tags: bug, bounties, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty notices are attributed to no one when the owner is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123504/bounty-notices-are-attributed-to-no-one-when-the-owner-is-deleted)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/98205/revisions) had a bounty put on it by a now **deleted** user, but the text just says:

> **Notice added** Current answers are outdated by

by who? ***I*** know it is by `user1385191` (formerly known as `********`  <sub><sup><sub><sup>name hidden to protect the innocent</sup></sub></sup></sub>).

Why isn't that name being shown?

Screenshot for posterity:

[image]

Possibly related: [Bounty notice for bounty offered by deleted/banned user has blank username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144383/155556)

Comment: @TimStone that is related, but not the same. In that question the issue was resolved. This is a new outcropping of it in a different way.

Comment: How is it not the same? The bug report is talking about exactly what you circled in your screenshot. I know, I wrote it.

Comment: @TimStone lol sorry. I thought you posted a link to the related question that I put in my OP. yes, this is a duplicate, but you have no screenshots for posterity :-P